# JQUERY: trigger a submit button when 2 fields change their values

Tags: jquery, button, triggers, submit

I need to send a click to a submit button when 2 separated fields change their values ("onHide"). The code is related with 2 calendars for hotel reservations.
Perhaps the solution is more simple that I think, but I'm really newbie with jquery.
The basic script:

```
$("#checkIn").bind("onHide", function()  { 
    checkIn = $("#checkIn").val();

    $.post('file.php', {"checkIn": checkIn}, function() {
        // do something more
    });
});


$("#checkOut").bind("onHide", function()  {  
    checkOut = $("#checkOut").val();

    $.post('file.php', {"checkOut": checkOut}, function() {
        // do something more
    });     
});
```

... So, the next step would be (when both fields change values):

```
$("#submitButton").trigger('click');
```

The function (onHide) works fine. 
BTW: checkOut depends on checkIn, but is not important.
I only need to know how to send the click to the submitButton.
Some suggestion, please? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be better off to just submit the form directly rather than try to simulate a click on a button:

```
document.forms[0].submit();//this will submit the first form found on the page
```

or with [JQuery's submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) (thanks @akalucas):

```
$("#form").sumbit();
```

---

If you need to do additional work on submit I would suggest binding a function to the click event of the submit button and then calling that function when you fields change:

```
$("#submitButton").click(SubmitForm);

function SubmitForm(){
   //something else I might need to do like validation
   document.forms[0].submit();
}

function AnyOtherFuntion(){
   SubmitForm();
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Based on the new information you might want something like this:

```
var checkInValue = "";
var checkOutValue = "";

$(document).onload(function(){
   checkInValue = $("#checkIn").val();
   checkOutValue = $("#checkOut").val();

   $("#checkIn").change(OnChange);
   $("#checkOut").change(OnChange);
});

function OnChange(){
   if(checkInValue != $("#checkIn").val() && checkOutValue != $("#checkOut").val()){
      SubmitForm();
   }
}

function SubmitForm(){
   document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: And if you want to use jQuery to submit the form, just use $("#form").sumbit()

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses! Probably I didn't explain my problem in the proper maner. I only need to know how I detect that these 2 fields changed their values. Perhaps by adding one variable or two, but I don't know how or where it should go that code. These fields are working almost as a SELECT, although they are 2 INPUT TEXT fields. When running "onHide" I can get the values of the fields but what I need is that when these 2 fields change, "something" execute the submit button.

Comment: On the other hand, it is needed for me simulate the click in the button because I need to refresh/reload the entire webpage, not just sending the data in the background.

Comment: @user1450818: Check out my edit, hope it help... oh, and the form submit function will post the page (and thus reload it if that is how you have it setup)

Comment: Thank you, again, Musefa. I couldn't use your original script as is, but I have used a fragment.  I  have applied your suggestion to my own script and my problem has been solved. Kind regards.

Comment: @Propagation: Glad to hear it, don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you. Only 9 more rep and you can start upvoting too!

Answer (score 0):

you can submit a form without clicking an submit better go for that

```
  document.form_name.submit();
```